# ruby on rails render deosn't find the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partial-views, render

I'm new to ruby on rails.

In views/events I have "_form.html.erb" which is rendered in "new.html.erb" by this code:

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

Now I want to render "_form.html.erb" in "index.html.erb" which is in the same folder(views/events).
But I get the error "missing template".

I guess I have to add some thing to controller, please help me to render form in other pages of views...

Comment: That definitely *should* work. Do we have more details on the error message? Was it written exactly the same, `<%= render "form" %>`, in the index page as well?

Comment: does it tell the path it's trying to find the partial at?

Comment: this is my error
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "usually" don't render a form in an index action. Most form partials are setup semantically to expect a `@my_resource`, but if you're doing everything the rails way you're not going to have a instance variable during your index action. There's a number of ways you can do this but this is probably the quickest.

You probably have some collection (let's pretend you're using books) in your index action:

```
#views/books/index.html.erb
<% @books.each do |book| %>
   ...
   <%= render "form" %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

You can just set an instance variable somewhere prior to rendering the form:

```
#views/books/index.html.erb
<% @books.each do |book| %>
   <% @book = book %>
   ...
   <%= render "form" %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

Another way to do it would be through passing in some locals to a partial. You'd have to change all of your references in `_form` to use a local variable instead. Then you can call render like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => {:book => book } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<%= render "events/form" %>
```

I had this problem before and this solved

Comment: Sorry you are right. Please check with "/events/form" instead of "events/form" and tell me if works.

Comment: Thanks again enrique... but still  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Do you have anything in your code that call an error method or attribute?

Comment: I added definition for new instance in controller for index and then it worked...thanks...

Comment: Ok, great. It worked with "form" or "events/form" in the partial??